# JQuery/Cycle2 - Go to URL and then call specific slide

Tags: jquery, cycle2

I am trying to link to a specific slide from another page.

The code i am using (within document.ready) is:

```
$('#goto1').click(function() { 
    window.location.href = "page.html#projects";
    setTimeout(function () {
    $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle(3); 
    return false;
    }, 5000);   
});
```

It goes to the URL in question, but then doesnt change the cycle-slideshow div to slide 3 - in fact nothing happens once redirected.

Obviously I am missing something - any ideas?

Comment: If you comment `window.location.href = "page.html#projects";` line then is it changing slide to 3?

Comment: No as the slideshow is on page.html and I am trying to call the slide from the index.html

Comment: Try this `$('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('goto', 3);` if it is working!

Comment: Doesnt make a difference - it doesnt call anything after the window.location.href

Comment: comment that window.location and use `$('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('goto', 3);` and see if it working!

Comment: So `cycle2` plugin is not set to the class `.cycle-slideshow`. Please fix that first?

Comment: It is - but you are missing the point - I need to go to a specific slide from a page other than where cycle-slideshow exists...

Comment: OK. So in every page where you have loaded cycle 2 on document ready you have to check the url # value and then set the cycle index as per that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used cycle2 built in functionality.

ie.

```
var slideshow = $('.cycle-slideshow');
maxSlides = slideshow.data('cycle.opts');

slideshow.on({
'cycle-update-view': function(event, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag) {
    UpdateTitles();
}
});

function UpdateTitles(){
var currentSlide = slideshow.data('cycle.opts').currSlide;
activeSlide = $(".cycle-slide-active");
activeTitle = activeSlide.data('title');

if(currentSlide == 0){
    nextTitle = activeSlide.next().data('title');
    prevTitle = '';
}
else if(currentSlide == maxSlides-1){
    prevTitle = activeSlide.prev().data('title');
    nextTitle = $(".cycle-slide").eq(0).data('title');
}
else {
    nextTitle = activeSlide.next().data('title');
    prevTitle = activeSlide.prev().data('title');
}

$('#prev').html(prevTitle);
$('#next').html(nextTitle);
}

UpdateTitles();

});
```